# Keep a value in a ViewModel even if the value is not modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, edit, actionresult

In a C# MVC 5 Internet application, I have a HTTP Get Edit action result, that gets an object, and places this object in a ViewModel and this is then displayed in a View.

One of the fields in the ViewModel is a value that is not edited in the view. In the HTTP Post Edit action, the value that is not edited in the view has been reset.

How can I keep this value so that it is the same value in the HTTP Post method as the HTTP Get method?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the ViewModel code:

```
public class MapLocationViewModel
{
    [Editable(false)]
    public int mapCompanyForeignKeyId { get; set; }
    public MapLocation mapLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code at the bottom of the HTTP Get Edit Action result, where the mapCompanyForeignKeyId is set:

```
MapLocationViewModel mapLocationViewModel = new MapLocationViewModel();
mapLocationViewModel.mapLocation = maplocation;
mapLocationViewModel.mapCompanyForeignKeyId = maplocation.mapCompanyForeignKeyId;
return View(mapLocationViewModel);
```

Here is the HTTP Post Edit Action result code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(MapLocationViewModel mapLocationViewModel)
```

In the above HTTP Edit Action result code, the mapLocationViewModel.mapCompanyForeignKeyId is reset to 0, after this value has been set to a number in the HTTP Get Edit Action result.

Comment: can you show how you've written you viewmodel class? Did you use the `Editable(false)` attribute?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try make hidden input. With Razor syntax it would be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{         
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YourProperty)
}
```

YourProperty will not be visible but it's value will be in the view model sent to the POST method.
You can also use HiddenInputAttribute for this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
public int YourProperty {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.MyField)` or similar helpers within a form, by default, it should automatically spit out all the existing values for each field and thus you should see all values whether modified or not. When it is posted, each included field will be serialized. If you use the helpers, you won't have to worry about naming convention as Razor and the model binder will do the work for you.

Check the request coming into your `POST` action to see if it is a model binding issue or a client issue. If you don't see the desired members in the body (or query string, if a GET) then you must not be sending them from the client, which can be due to improper serialization/naming of fields, not including the field in the page, not sending the value of the field to the page, or including the field outside of the form, among other reasons...

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

...

@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", ...)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field1)
    @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Field1)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field2)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Field2)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

...

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         return MyGetAction(model);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit? Do I have to write any code in the View to get the ViewModel value?

Comment: @user3736648 you need to also post your Razor, because that is what determines which fields get sent over...

Comment: I have figured it out. All I needed was an @Html.HiddenFor line of code in the Razor view.

Comment: Good to hear. Again, your Razor determines what gets sent over - whether it is through a `HiddenFor` or a `TextAreaFor` or whatever